# Custom data annotation attribute are static

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

I have class named AuthenticatToken which looks like this

```
public class TokenBasedAuthentication : ActionFilterAttribute, IAuthenticationFilter
{
    ILocalData local = null;
    string token = string.Empty;
    bool istokenvalid = false;

    public async Task AuthenticateAsync(HttpAuthenticationContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        istokenvalid = false;
        await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            var req = context.Request;

            IEnumerable<string> headervalues = new List<string>();
            bool hastoken = req.Headers.TryGetValues(Constants.TOKEN, out headervalues);

            if (hastoken)
            {
                local = new LocalData();
                token = headervalues.FirstOrDefault();
                istokenvalid = local.ValidateToken(token);
            }

            if (!istokenvalid)
            {
                context.ErrorResult = new AuthenticationFailureResult("Invalid token when accessing service", req);
            }
            else
            {
                IPrincipal incomingprincipal = context.ActionContext.RequestContext.Principal;
                context.Principal = incomingprincipal;
            }
        });
    }

    public Task ChallengeAsync(HttpAuthenticationChallengeContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
}
```

the issue is when calling the above class as custom data annotation in controller the variables are not initialized it uses previous values for second request to controller.

```
[TokenBasedAuthentication]
public class SettingsController : ApiController, ISettings
{
}
```

so my question is are data annotation static ?

Comment: I think the Attribute object is stored at application level. I have tried this with different clients & the variables store previous values but if you restart the application, the values are gone. You always learn something new everyday in this field!!!

Comment: Annotations are created per type, not per instance. It's not quite the same as being static, but you definitely can't expect to perform instance-specific logic on the annotation without giving the instance as parameter.